# Compering undefined, null and values

Tags: javascript

I want to run this in my code:  `if(a > b){ do something}` where a and b can be sometimes undefined or null and sometimes comparable(e.g. both a number).
Is it ok in javascript to do this?
I only want the `if` to be true if they are comparable.

Comment: So if both `a` and `b` are undefined, what should `a > b` be, in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should never attempt to compare things of different types without defining your rules for how you want them to be compared. While there's actually a very strict set of rules defined in JS standard for comparing values of different types, you're opening the big can of worms if you try to design your code around this set.

What you might consider doing instead is separating type casting operation from comparison operation. For example:

```
function firstIsGreater(numA, numB) {
   if (typeof numA !== 'number') return false;
   if (typeof numB !== 'number') return false;    

   return numA > numB;
}
```

Strictly speaking, those checks are not required here. For example, when you compare with `undefined`, that gets cast to `NaN`, and any comparison involving `NaN` results in `false`.

The problem is that usually mixture of types is a sign of much bigger problems in your outlying code - and instead of returning false you might consider throwing errors, or at least triggering some warnings.

In general you should validate the values and cast them to the types you're completely aware of at the very moment those values arrive into your system from some external components - server-side calls, user input etc.

Comment: `NaN` compared to anything including itself is always false though so while I agree with explicit casting, the explicit checks are unecessary.

Comment: That's a good point, but I was actually going to suggest throwing there anyway. Will add this there.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof a == 'number' && typeof b == 'number' && a > b){ do something}
```

This will only run "do something" if a and b are both numbers and a is greater than b.

Comment: Yep, zeroes are overrated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Any `undefined` value in combination with a comparison of less than `<`, greater than `>` or less than or equal or graater than or equal yields `false`.

Any `null` value is converted to zero in an number like environment.

Maybe this table helps: [Loose equality using `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using)

```js
if (undefined < 3) console.log('undefined < 3');
if (undefined > 3) console.log('undefined > 3');
if (undefined <= 3) console.log('undefined <= 3');
if (undefined >= 3) console.log('undefined >= 3');

if (null < 3) console.log('null < 3');
if (null > 3) console.log('null > 3');
if (null <= 3) console.log('null <= 3');
if (null >= 3) console.log('null >= 3');
```